# glm::lookAt returns matrix with nan elements

Tags: opengl, 3d, glm-math

I want to create a view matrix for a camera which perpendicularly look at the ground:

```
glm::mat4 matrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

The last argument is the global up vector so everything seems to be correct but I get following matirx:

```
-nan    -nan    -0  0   
-nan    -nan     1  0   
-nan    -nan    -0  0   
 nan     nan    -1  1
```

I guess that I get nan because a look at vector is parallel to up vector, but how can I build a correct view matrix using glm::lookAt function.

Comment: I was developing using `webGl`. In my case the issue was that I was using mat4.lookAt() (http://glmatrix.net/docs/module-mat4.html) as gluLookAt() (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml). was passing 9 parameters, instead of passing vec3. Incorrect : `mat4.lookAt(camView, camPos[0], camPos[1], camPos[2], 0,0,0, 0,1,0);` correct : `mat4.lookAt(camView, vec3.fomrValues(camPos[0], camPos[1], camPos[2]), vec3.fomrValues(0,0,0), vec3.fomrValues(0,1,0));`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with either your camera's position, or the up vector.

Your camera is 1 unit up (0,1,0), looking down at the origin (0,0,0). The up vector indicates the up direction of the camera, not the world space. For example, if you're looking forward, the up vector would be +Y. If you're looking down, with the top of your head facing +X, then the up vector is +X to you. It has to be something that's not at all parallel with the position vector of the camera.

Solutions:

- Changing the up vector to anything along the XZ plane
- or to something that's not (0,0,0) when projected onto the XZ plane
- Move your camera so that it's anywhere but along the Y axis

Answer (score 5):

In `lookAt` it is impossible to have the viewing direction and the up-vector looking in the same direction. If you want to have a camera that is looking along the negative y-axis, you'll have to adjust the up-vector, for example to `[0,0,1]`. The direction one specifies in the up-vector controls how the camera is rotated around the view axis.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same problem of NaNs in the matrix returned by glm::lookAt() yesterday and have concocted what I think is a workaround. This seems to work for me for the particular problem of the UP vector being vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), which seems to be a common use case.

My Vulkan code looks like this:

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 proj;
};
...
        UniformBufferObject ubo{};
...
        glm::vec3 cameraPos = glm::vec3(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
        ubo.view = glm::lookAt(cameraPos, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

        // if the direction vector from the camera to the point being observed ends up being parallel to the UP vector
        // glm::lookAt() returns a mat4 with NaNs in it. to workaround this, look for NaNs in ubo.view
        int view_contains_nan = 0;

        for (int col = 0; (col < 4) && !view_contains_nan; ++col) {
            for (int row = 0; (row < 4) && !view_contains_nan; ++row) {
                if (std::fpclassify(ubo.view[col][row]) == FP_NAN) {
                    view_contains_nan = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // if we ended up with NaNs, the workaround ubo.view that seems to work depends on the sign of the camera position Y
        if (view_contains_nan) {
            std::cout << "view contains NaN"  << std::endl;
            if (cameraPos.y >= 0.0f) {
                ubo.view = glm::mat4(   -0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,        0.0f,
                             0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,        0.0f,
                            -1.0f,  0.0f, -0.0f,        0.0f,
                            -0.0f, -0.0f, -cameraPos.y, 1.0f);
            } else {
                ubo.view = glm::mat4(    0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,        0.0f,
                             0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,        0.0f,
                            -1.0f,  0.0f, -0.0f,        0.0f,
                            -0.0f,  -0.0f, cameraPos.y, 1.0f);
            }
        }
```

Hopefully it works for you too, though I suppose it would be nice if glm::lookAt() could be fixed to not return matrices with NaNs in it.